# how is solr working with the "catch-all" field _text_?

Tags: solr

When extracting a file, solr indexes its content to a catch-all field named `_text_`. This is the case despite if you give a content field via `fmap.content=my_content_field`.

But, the field `_text_` seems to be overwritten on update if there was no `fmap.content` field declared. If `fmap.content` was declared, the field `_text_` stays apparently unchanged.

To reproduce this behaviour:

```sh
SOLR_CORE=test
SOLR_URL=http://192.168.45.153:8983/solr/${SOLR_CORE}
FILENAME=textfile.txt

cat > ${FILENAME} << EOF
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
EOF
```

delete all documents in the core

```sh
curl "${SOLR_URL}/update?commit=true&stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>"
```

add a document, extract and index the contents of filename.txt:

```sh
curl "${SOLR_URL}/update/extract?\
literal.id=${FILENAME}\
&fmap.content=my_content_field\
&literal.field_x=initial_text_of_field_x\
&literal.field_y=initial_text_of_field_y\
&commit=true"\
 -F "myfile=@${FILENAME}"
```

query for documents containing the word `ipsum`:

```sh
curl "${SOLR_URL}/query?q=_text_:ipsum&fl=id"
```

update the content of the field `field_x`:

```sh
curl "${SOLR_URL}/update?commit=true" -d '
[
  {
    "id" : '${FILENAME}',
    "field_x" : {"set" : "new_value"}
  }
]'
```

query for documents containing the word `ipsum`:

```sh
curl "${SOLR_URL}/query?q=_text_:ipsum&fl=id"
```

The queries before and after updating give results with the document found as expected:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"_text_:ipsum",
      "fl":"id"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"textfile.txt"}]
  }}
```

if the document was added without `&fmap.content=my_content_field`:

```sh
curl "${SOLR_URL}/update/extract?\
literal.id=${FILENAME}\
&literal.field_x=initial_text_of_field_x\
&literal.field_y=initial_text_of_field_y\
&commit=true"\
 -F "myfile=@${FILENAME}"
```

The query after updating (see above) finds no documents:

```sh
curl "${SOLR_URL}/query?q=_text_:ipsum&fl=id"
```

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"_text_:ipsum",
      "fl":"id"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that **update** command has to reconstruct the document, update it and submit it back to Lucene storage layer. That's because, on Lucene level, the content is write only. Solr-level update actually generates a new Lucene document under the covers.

So, to reconstruct the document, it needs to be able to get the fields back. And if the field is not stored (or docValued, I think), there is no way to do so.

The ***text*** field is most likely not stored, as it usually accumulates content of many other fields for the convenient default search. So, it does not participate in reconstruction and the updated document misses it.

My guess is that **my_content_field** is defined with **stored=true** and therefore can be included in the reconstructed document and saved back together with updates.